# Start ipython notebook with predefined imports

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I do have several predefined settings. E.g the visual properties of my matplotlib plots (via rc-file) or some custom modules. My first cell of my notebook looks always the same e.g

```
#Import of my personal plot properties and functions, classes etc..
if os.name == 'nt':
    sys.path.append('R:/../mypy')
    rc_file('R:/.../dissertation.rc')
elif os.name == 'posix':
    sys.path.append('/home/moritz/..(/mypy/')
    rc_file('/home/moritz/.../dissertation.rc')

import Wellplate as rwp # my readwellplate class
import my_functions as mf # my function collection
```

Is it possible to start every new notebook automatically with these settings ?

Comment: Yep, it is a duplicate. THX